# How can I solve that when I click on a button it is translated to the right?

Tags: html, css, button

Sorry for my bad English.

I have a button (access without login) in a form, problem, when I click on it, it is translated, on the right.

My code

```css
.inviteBtn {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 40px;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 6px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .13);
  border: none;
  outline: 0;
  background-image: var(--gradient);
  color: white;
  border-radius: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  margin-right: -50px;
}
```

```html
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" class="inviteForm">
  <button name="invite" class="inviteBtn">Access without login</button>
</form>
```

What it looks like:

[image: what it looks like]

I think it's due to the translate but it serves to center the button.

Your help would be really appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: The code you posted doesn't reproduce the problem you describe. Incidentally, a `<button>` in a `<form>` will submit that form; you may wish to amend your `<button>` to: `<button type="button" name="invite" class="inviteBtn">`... to prevent form-submission.

Comment: It's a simplified version, there are others buttons in that form. The php file checks if the button with name "invitite" is submited.

Comment: That's fine, but the code you post needs to replicate the problem otherwise we can't help fix the problem (because we can't see it, or interact with it).